# Django no such column even after migrations

Tags: django

This is my model code

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    edited_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="X vs Y")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="A poll")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title



class Item(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey('Poll',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    edited_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    type_of = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

You see votes in Item model right. That's a problem. I use `makemigrations` `migrate` command. But I still get no such column error.

Edit:
This is `makemigrations vs_chart` output

```
Migrations for 'vs_chart':
  vs_chart\migrations\0001_initial.py:
    - Create model Item
    - Create model Poll
    - Add field poll to item
```

This is `migrate` command output.

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: vs_chart
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you add field poll to item, you may try to provide default value for ForeignKey, absence of default value may cause this issue:

```
poll = models.ForeignKey('Poll',on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0)
```

Comment: It work except for votes option is show as
'Votes : votes' I use '{% for item in poll.item_set.all  %} Votes: {% item.votes %}'

Comment: i'm sorry, what do you mean? what is not working now?

Comment: I accidently press enter.

Comment: am i answer your question?

Comment: Template render except value of votes show as 'votes' instead of number.

Comment: this is another question, and not related to this question, provide your template and view code